# Не считает сумму в массиве

Tags: javascript

```
function range(start, end){
var array=[];
for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
    array.push(i);
}
return array;
}

console.log(range(5,8));

function sum(array){
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   total += array[i];
   return total;
}
   console.log(sum());
```

Выдаёт 2 errorа в консоли. В чём ошибка?
P.S. Нашёл ошибку. console.log(sum(range(a,b)));

Comment: хотябы текст ошибок приложите

Comment: А вы параметр не задаете кода делете `call` функции `sum`, надо sum (simple_array);

Comment: ну так, а какую сумму ты хочешь посчитать в `undefined`?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at sum (src.js:164)
    at src.js:168

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что нужно было передать данные в функцию `sum()` в той области видимости, в которой идет вызов этой функции вот так `sum(arr)` (например). А вы передавали пустоту и от этого функция выдавала `undefined`.

**Рабочий пример:**

```js
function range(start, end){
var array=[];
for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
    array.push(i);
}
return array;
}
// используем переменную для удобства, чтобы передать ее в функцию sum ниже
var arr=range(5,8);
console.log(arr);

function sum(array){
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   total += array[i];
   return total;
}
// передаем "массив"
console.log(sum(arr));
```